# Complex of Abelian groups

Tags: notation, sheaf-theory

I will be grateful if someone could explain the meaning of product notation in the following paragraphs:

- From pp. 35 of Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*:
  [image: (c) 2002, Qing Liu]
- Ravi Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*:
  [image: (c) November 2017, Ravi Vakil]

This is my first time ever reading about sheaves, and I don't have much exposure to category theory.

Comment: The product notation is simply $(s_i)_{i\in I}$ for $\prod_{i\in I}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is it like inner direct product or a tuple like outer direct product?

Comment: The latter one.